# How to choose between this 3 options for og:image

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-opengraph, advanced-custom-fields

I tried to code something like this:

1. If post does't have thumbnail it choose a default image.
2. If no ACF image is there then chose default thumbnail
3. If ACF image is there then use it.

it is for my og:image for facebook.

```
function insert_image_src_rel_in_head()
{
    global $post;
    if (!is_singular())
        return;
    if (!has_post_thumbnail($post->ID))
    {
        $default_image = "http://madmax.quebec/neufsvies/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/madmax.quebec_qaygerxdm814v-750x374.jpg";
        echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . $default_image . '"/>';
    }
    elseif (!empty($temp_acfImage))
    {
        $temp_acfImage = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_field('image_og'), 'facebook-thumbnail');
        echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . esc_attr($temp_acfImage[0]) . '"/>';
    }
    else
    {
        $thumbnail_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'facebook-thumbnail');
        echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . esc_attr($thumbnail_src[0]) . '"/>';
    }
    echo "";
}

add_action('wp_head', 'insert_image_src_rel_in_head', 1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
<?php
function insert_image_src_rel_in_head()
{
    global $post;
    $img_src = '';
    $default_image = "http://madmax.quebec/neufsvies/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/madmax.quebec_qaygerxdm814v-750x374.jpg"; //default image src
    if (!is_singular())
        return;
    $acfImage = get_field('image_og', $post->ID);
    //if post has ACF 'image_og'
    if (!empty($acfImage))
    {
        $img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($acfImage, 'facebook-thumbnail');
    }
    //if post does't has ACF 'image_og' but has thumbnail
    else if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID))
    {
        $img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'facebook-thumbnail')[0];
    }
    //if post does't has thumbnail and also does't has ACF 'image_og' then set a default image
    else
    {
        $img_src = $default_image;
    }

    ?>
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $img_src; ?>"/>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'insert_image_src_rel_in_head', 5);
?>
```

> [`wp_get_attachment_url`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url) it returns URI to uploaded attachment or
>   "false" on failure; whereas [`wp_get_attachment_image_src`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) it
>   returns an array contains four values: the URL of the attachment image
>   src, the width of the image file, the height of the image file, and a
>   boolean. And `wp_get_attachment_url` only takes `$attachment_id` as param and > `wp_get_attachment_image_src` accept `$attachment_id`, `$size`.

*Code is untested but it should work.*
Hope this helps!

Comment: ok and if i want the acf image to be first,

if there acf image use it
if there no acf image use thumbnail
and if there no acf image and thumbnail use default

Comment: doesn't work it's seem to only list the thumbnail and not the acf image

Comment: @MaximeMarquette: I fixed a typo error, now if you have AFC image it will work; provide the ACF key is `image_og`.

Comment: ok with the last version <meta property="og:image" content="Array" /> but if i change  $img_src; to  $img_src[0]; the acf field work but on post that doesn't have acf image <meta property="og:image" content="h" /> i'm getting this in og debug and by the way thank you very much for your time and patience we are near a solution i feel it.

Comment: `$img_src = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'facebook-thumbnail');` to `$img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'facebook-thumbnail');` and `<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $img_src; ?>"/>` by `<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $img_src[0]; ?>"/>` and it's now working

Comment: @MaximeMarquette: I'm into WordPress development form last 2yrs but never notice that `wp_get_attachment_url` only accept `$attachment_id`; because of you I get to know this point, please read my updated answer it might help you as well, thanks again.

Comment: i tried multiple test and $img_src; should be $img_src[0]; since it need to provide a url i think i don't know why

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src
[0] => url
[1] => width
[2] => height
[3] => boolean: true if $url is a resized image, false if it is the original or if no image is available.